# How to set a MySQL Trigger the correct way

Tags: mysql, triggers

i have a database table that gets updated via a CMS. Sometimes, there is one field that gets updated and then another field should get updated as well. I tried to get this done by just modifying the php code of the CMS, where the value gets saved in the DB. The problem is, with every update of the CMS this is gone.

I came across MySQL Triggers and i think this is a good way to do this. So whenever this field is updated, it should also update the other field with a value that will always be the same. But i cant quite get my head around the syntax, to get this going...

I tried:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_unique_content_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON articles FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.date <> new.date THEN
        INSERT INTO release=2020
    END IF;
END
```

But it is not working. So what i try to do: Every time in the CMS someone changes the date, the release for that db entry should be set to 2020. The standard for release is NULL. With the above trigger, nothing happens after the date is changed... Never worked with Trigger or Events in MySQL before...
How can i set the release to 2020 when the date field for that entry is updated?

Thanks for your help in advance!

best regards

Comment: You need a before trigger and SET release. Please read manual for examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_unique_content_update
BEFORE UPDATE
ON articles 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.release = CASE WHEN OLD.date <> NEW.date
                       THEN 2020
                       ELSE NEW.release
                       END;
```

Firstly the condition is checked by the trigger, and, if the condition matched, new value to the column is set to 2020 (or, maybe, it's better to set it not to `2020` but to `YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)`?). If the condition not matched then the value is not altered (assigned value is the same as current one).

After the trigger performs this task, actual table data update is performed.

AFTER UPDATE trigger is not applicable - when it fires the data in the table is already set to the value specified in a query.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. So the trigger gets fired up when a change to the date field is happening and makes the changes to the release field? I think this works, but i dont really understand why. Nevertheless thank you! I marked as correct answer.

Comment: @youwhatmate *So the trigger gets fired up when a change to the date field is happening and makes the changes to the release field?*  Trigger fires always when a row should be updated. It fires for each separate row update attempt - i.e. when 10 rows are updated the trigger is fired 10 times.

Comment: Ah now i see! Thank you! e.g. i have three of the date fields and if one of those gets updated the release should be set to 2018. How can i manage multiple statements? Can i just write another case?

Comment: @youwhatmate *i have three of the date fields and if one of those gets updated* `CASE WHEN (OLD.d1 != NEW.d1) OR (OLD.d2 != NEW.d2) ..`